# How to make div 100% in availble browser space?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to make third row (red one) 100% height in available browser space. Please let me know how can I achieve this? It should be flexible if I reduce the height of browser.

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/33Kzu/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="first_row">first row</div>
  <div class="second_row">second row</div>
  <div class="third_row">third row</div>
  <div class="fourth_row">fourth row</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}
.first_row, .second_second, .fourth_row {
  height:50px;
}
.first_row {
  background:gray;
}
.second_row {
  background:#ccc;
}
.third_row {
  height:100%;
  background:red;
}
.fourth_row {
  background:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: set body height and then % to to the other rows

Answer (score 0):

**// Edited due to more specific description of question author:**

If you want your 4 rows together to always be as high as the parent (body), whereas the 1,2 and 4th row have only a height of `50px`, try this:

CSS:

```
html,body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.div-table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.div-table-row {
    display:table-row;
}

.div-table-row:nth-child(1),.div-table-row:nth-child(2),.div-table-row:nth-child(4) {
    height:50px; 
    background-color:#cccccc;
}

.div-table-row:nth-child(3) {
    background-color:red;
}

.div-table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-cell first-content">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-cell first-content">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-cell first-content">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-cell first-content">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33Kzu/8/

**Next time, please use the search, as this is a `CSS` basic and should not be asked but searched for.**

Comment: no, .third-row is now 100% of window height, I think he wants the 4 rows together to equal 100% window height.

Comment: As far as I understood his question (`I want to make third row (red one) 100% height in available browser space.`), he is asking how to make the third row to 100% height of the body.

Comment: I understood `available browser space` as the white space remaining on the page, not to push past 100% of the window

Comment: Ah, now I see how you interpreted the question. Good point, depends on what the author intended to ask. Seems like the question's not 100% clear formulated here. Thanks for the hint, @rorypicko!

Comment: Sorry guys, I was not able to clarify the question clearly. I really appreciate your (codezombie) efforts. This is not what I wanted exactly but we are very close. Can we stop scrolling?

Comment: @AwaisImran I have upadted my answer.

Comment: Worth noting that using `display:table-*;` is not supported in IE 6/7